# Remove stop codon from file and replace it with NNN

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I want to write Perl code which checks for stop codon and replaces it with `NNN`. I have written code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Check if the file name is provided as an argument
my $file = $ARGV[0];

open(my $fh, "<", $file) or die "Unable to open file";

my $sequence = "";
my $id = "";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp($line);
    if ($line =~ /^>/) {
        if ($sequence ne "") {
            # Split sequence into codons
            my @codon = $sequence =~ /.{1,3}/g;
            print join(" ", @codon), "\n";
            print $id, "\n";

            # Check for stop codons and replace them with "NNN"
            foreach my $codon (@codon) {
                if ($codon =~ /^(TAG|TGA|TAA)/) {
                    $codon = "NNN";
                }
            }
        }
        $sequence = "";
        $id = $line;
    } else {
        $sequence .= $line;
    }
}

# Print last sequence
if ($sequence) {
    my @codon = $sequence =~ /.{1,3}/g;
    print join(" ", @codon), "\n";
    print $id, "\n";

}

close($fh) or die "Unable to close file";
```

Which should take input from command line, i.e fasta sequence, and process it: Split the sequence in multiples of three, replace stop codon with `NNN`.

I have the input sequence like:

```
>header 
ATGGACCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGTAA
```

I was expecting some thing like:

```
>header 
ATGGACCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGNNN
```

Also it did not process the last sequence in the file, and I got output as:

```
>header
ATG GAC CAG CAG CAG CAG CAG CAG TAA
```

Except header of the first sequence and sequence of the last header were missing.

Comment: My header starts with ">" and sequences start with new line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution did not occur because the logic of your program is incorrect.  The following condition is never true, so your replacement code does not get executed:

```
if ($sequence ne "")
```

Then, in the `# Print last sequence` code, you don't try to do the substitution.

Here is a self-contained example that does the substitution:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp($line);
    if ($line =~ /^>/) {
        print "$line\n";
    } else {
        # Split sequence into codons
        my @codon = $line =~ /.{1,3}/g;

        # Check for stop codons and replace them with "NNN"
        foreach my $codon (@codon) {
            if ($codon =~ /^(TAG|TGA|TAA)/) {
                $codon = "NNN";
            }
        }
        print join(" ", @codon), "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
>header 
ATGGACCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGTAA
```

Output:

```
>header 
ATG GAC CAG CAG CAG CAG CAG CAG NNN
```

See also: [bioperl](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bioperl/info)